# ajax pass object to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

HomeController:

```
      [HttpPost]
      public JsonResult SetDefaultHomeCategoryOrder(CategoryOrderModel categories)
            {


                return Json(new { msg = "ok" });
            }

            public class CategoryOrderModel
            {
                public int DisplayOrder;
                public int CategoryId;
            }


View: 

                     var operationCollection = new CategoryOrderModel();


      $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SetDefaultHomeCategoryOrder", "Home")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(operationCollection),
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.msg);

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
```

The controller never gets the correct parameter??

UPDATED: I changed the code to accept the collection

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SetDefaultHomeCategoryOrder(List<CategoryOrderModel> categories)
        {         

            return Json(new { msg = 'ok' });
        }
```

View:

```
 var collection = [];
 var col1= new CategoryOrderModel(1,2);
 collection.push(col1);
var col2= new CategoryOrderModel(2,5);
 collection.push(col2);
$.ajax({
            url: '/Home/SetDefaultHomeCategoryOrder/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{ categories : ' + JSON.stringify(collection) + '}',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.msg);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });


function CategoryOrderModel(displayOrder, categoryId) {
        var self = this;
        self.DisplayOrder = displayOrder;
        self.CategoryId = categoryId;
    }
```

Comment: `SetDefaultHomeCategoryOrder` - there's no evidence in your question that this action even exists.

Comment: I think you need to replace "SetDefaultHomeCategoryOrder" with your action method SetCategoryOrder

Comment: Have you tried using firebug or another debugger to see the console output?

Comment: ReferenceError: CategoryOrderModel is not defined

var operationCollection = new CategoryOrderModel(); >> that's from firebug console

Comment: Thus you're using a server side C# object on the client side. Which doesn't work try @RollerCosta solution, that should work.

Comment: no, i'm not trying to use server class on client side. I've just updated my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are the errors in your code

1.Your model dont have getters and setters

```
public class CategoryOrderModel
{
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

2.Since it is javascript , operationCollection is model so it will not work instead deaclare a variable

```
  var CategoryOrderModel =
  {
      "DisplayOrder": "7",
      "CategoryId": "9"
  };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SetCategoryOrder", "Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: '{ categories : ' + JSON.stringify(CategoryOrderModel) + '}',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.msg);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
```

Comment: don't know why i miss out the '{ categories : ', guess i need a cup of coffee to continue :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As we know MVC works on the principle of name/value pair i.e. on Strongly type view along with Model binding.

Possibly you can do:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("SetDefaultHomeCategoryOrder", "Home")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {'DisplayOrder' : 9 , 'CategoryId' : 1},
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data.msg);

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
```

Notice data key/value `data: {'DisplayOrder' : 9 , 'CategoryId' : 1},`, this is somewhat similar to post a form in MVC.

Generally we use `$('#formId').serialize()` to send collection from view to controller with jquery/ajax.

Comment: thanks i understand it would work but i later will pass a collection of CategoryModel to controller. That's why i try with one object first.

Comment: For that you can use Ajax.BeginForm(), if help.

Comment: i dont' submit a form, i'm using jqueryUI Sortable to allow users to move around the order of categories list and save the arrangement to cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass the data to controller "SetDefaultHomeCategoryOrder" or "SetCategoryOrder"
if Action name is SetCategoryOrder then type

```
url:@Url.Action('SetCategoryOrder','Home')
```

Answer (score -1):

Your methods don't match from view you are calling SetDefaultHomeCategoryOrder but inside the controller it's called SetCategoryOrder

Comment: Patrick if he's battling to get the method called in the first place, I doubt if he has modified the default routing

Comment: sorry for typos, that's not the problem.