# Binding parameter issue when post JSON data to MVC controller with hidden field

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am a JSON object in a form which allows users to add options. I want to post this JSON to a ASP.NET MVC controller as a hidden field WITHOUT Ajax. I researched a couple of posts and tried to do this, but without luck. What I have done so far is:

1. Backend Parameter Object

```
    public class Person 
    { 
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

2. Backend Controller

```
    public class BookingController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddPerson(Person person)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

3. Frontend Javascript & Html

```
    <form action="/booking/addperson" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="person" id="person" />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>

      <script>
          var person = { "Name": "ML", "Email": "ml@m.com" }
          $("#person").val(JSON.stringify(person));
      </script>
    </form>
```

Unfortunately, when I submitted the form on step 3, the parameter in the controller was null, but I could find the actually data in the Request object inside the controller. (see screenshot below)

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know what do I miss to actually bind the JSON object to the controller parameter when posting a form? Thanks!

Comment: Hi,Any update about this case?

Answer (score 1):

> var person = { "Name": "ML", "Email": "ml@m.com" }
> $("#person").val(JSON.stringify(person));

This code will change `#person`'s val as a string,but you use the object type to accept in the background.So it will be null.

You can change your `AddPerson` method as follow:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddPerson(string person)
    {
        Person model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(person);
        return View();
    }
```

***Update***

Or you can change your view code like below:

```
<form action="/booking/addperson" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="name" id="name" />
   <input type="hidden" name="email"  id="email"/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>

  <script>
      var person = { "Name": "ML", "Email": "ml@m.com" }
      $("#name").val(person.Name);
      $("#email").val(person.Email);
  </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. You solution would work, however, it is not ideal and requires to change the parameter object type. I am wondering if there is a way to bind the object instead of using string.

Comment: Hi @seanbun,you can see my update answer.

Comment: In other words, you reckon there is no way we can post the JSON object to the controller?

Comment: Yes,Unless you use ajax,You can see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755197/ajax-pass-object-to-controller).